# Music organization into folders for Linux(Ubuntu/Debian)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mp3, file-organization

I have a few folders with randomly assorted music files.  I'm looking for a tool or utility that can read the ID3 tags, and then build and populate a folder structure in the format:

*some dir*/Artist/songs*

I've used MediaMonkey on Windows, but not sure what to use for Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Picard Musicbrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) is a good program for what you need.
You can use it on Linux as well as Windows.

Answer (score 1):

check out [**SortTv**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sorttv/), its designed for sorting downloaded TV shows, but it also works for music

I use it in Ubuntu.