# Organizing Music Folders

Tags: music-management

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Music organization into folders for linux(ubuntu/debian)?](https://superuser.com/questions/251389/music-organization-into-folders-for-linuxubuntu-debian)
>   [How to organize music?](https://superuser.com/questions/87792/how-to-organize-music)

Previously on Linux, I added tracks to Rhythmbox and it automatically placed them in an order like this:

Artist > Album > Tracks

Two years and 3000 tracks later, my Music folder is a disaster. Is there any program that can replicate what Rhythmbox once did for me, as well as maintain these folders?

I currently use Winamp as my player of choice, but will be happy to switch if there is a greater alternative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Music organization into folders for linux(ubuntu/debian)?](http://superuser.com/questions/251389/music-organization-into-folders-for-linuxubuntu-debian) -- but then I forgot that you're now running Windows :) For Windows, there are a [couple of others](http://superuser.com/questions/87792/how-to-organize-music) as well. Here's one [for the tagging side](http://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s) of things.

Comment: I long since stopped trying to organise my music directory, once I realised I was never, ever going to manage it in anything that didn't understand tags.

Comment: Oh and personally, I've always used [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) to fetch info and also play music.

Comment: @slhck Those are more to do with the organization of adjusting the music, and was to do with "tagging, removing duplicates." I'm looking more at the actual organization of the files.

Comment: Oh, I guess MediaMonkey can do that (folder renaming). Also, there's [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) and [EasyTAG](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) that you might want to look at -- I recall both having those features you want (not 100% sure though). But they're also listed in the linked Q/As above with a feature list.

Comment: That was already said @Techie, and I explained my question more in the comment

Comment: iTunes can do that, IIRC. But it's been over 6 months since I used iTunes, so not sure

Comment: @Simon Sheehan - I missed slhck's link. Still stands though, it's  (basically) the same question.